# Code from application_controller.rb is not inherited by other controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I read that the use of the `ApplicationController` is to treat it like the parent of all other controllers. Any code that goes into it will also run in all other controllers. Because I use my app more like an API I put `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` in my application_controller.rb file so I can utilize my app from external domains. For some reason it does not work (it still blocks the connection). Instead I had to put that line of code into every single controller to make it work (authentication is now skipped / app can be utilized by external domains).

While it isn't much trouble to put the code in every conroller I'm confused about the correct usage of the ApplicationController and wonder if I did something wrong.

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Here is the code of the `ApplicationController`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
end
```

Here is the code of another controller (Note: the `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` should be removed / inherited by the `ApplicationController` as dscribed above.

```
class SessionsController < ActionController::Base
  include CurrentUserConcern

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params["user"]["email"]).try(:authenticate, params["user"]["password"])

    if User
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      render json: {
        status: :created,
        logged_in: true,
        user: user
      }
    else
      render json: {
        status: 401
      }
    end
  end

  def logged_in
    if @current_user
      render json: {
        logged_in: true,
        user: @current_user
      }
    else
      render json: {
        logged_in: false
      }
    end
  end

  def logout
    reset_session
    render json: {
      status: 200,
      logged_out: true
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `SessionsController` is inheriting from `ActionController::Base` change the class definition of sessionsController from `class SessionsController < ActionController::Base` to `class SessionsController < ApplicationController`. It will not automatically inherit from applicationController you have to specify it in the controllers where you want to inherit from it.

Comment: my pleasure. :)